# Metric on the space $\lbrace (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3 , \langle u,v\rangle=0 \rbrace$

Tags: general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces, orthogonality

Consider the following set :
$$\Omega=\lbrace (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3 , \langle u,v\rangle=0 \rbrace$$

where $\langle ,\rangle$ is the canonical scalar product of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

- Except that it is the **set of all pairs of orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$**, what can be said about this specific space?
- Does exist any **metric** to define a distance $d(x,y)$ between two elements $x,y\in\Omega$?
- Is their any interesting **geometrical or topological properties** related to such mathematical object?

Comment: The relation $\langle u | v\rangle =0$ is not an equivalence relation, so that is not a quotient of $\mathbb R^3$. It is an algebraic variety in $\mathbb R^6$.

Comment: Use `$\langle X\rangle$` for $\langle X\rangle$.

Comment: You have at least two choices of metric: that of $\mathbb{R}^6$ or the metric given by the length of the shortest curve joining $x$ and $y$ in $\Omega$.

Comment: I mean there is always the trivial metric $$d(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{if $x=y$} \\ 1 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the set of all points $x=(x_1,...,x_6)\in\Bbb R^6$ with

$$x_1x_4+x_2x_5+x_3x_6=0.$$

You can write this as

$$x^T Mx=0,\qquad\text{with } M=\left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}&&&1\\&&&&1\\&&&&&1\\\hline 1\\&1\\&&1\end{array}\right).$$

This matrix provides an orthonormal basis of six eigenvectors to non-zero eigenvalues $\{+1,+1,+1,-1,-1,-1\}$. Instead of the standard basis of $\Bbb R^6$, express your vectors in this new basis. So if $x=(\hat x_1,...,\hat x_6)\in\Bbb R^6$ (the coordinates are w.r.t this new basis), then we have

$$x^TMx=0\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \hat x_1^2+\hat x_2^2+\hat x_3^2=\hat x_4^2+\hat x_5^2+\hat x_6^2.$$

So you also can say $\Omega=\{(u,v)\in\Bbb R^3\times\Bbb R^3\mid \|u\|^2=\|v\|^2\}$. This shows that $\Omega$ is topologically equivalent to $\Bbb R^3\times \Bbb S^2$ after associating all $\{0\}\times\Bbb S^2$ with a single point. So it is *kind of* a [topological cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)) but not exactly.

Answer (score 1):

- Question. Except that it is the **set of all pairs of orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$**, what can be said about this specific space?
- Answer. $\Omega$ is the kernel of bilinear form $K:\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $K(u,v)=\langle u,v\rangle $.
- Question. Does exist any **metric** to define a distance $d(x,y)$ between two elements $x,y\in\Omega$?
- Answer. Let $x=(u,v)$ and $y=(w,z)$. Then 
  $$
  d(x,y)=\sqrt{\|u-w\|^2_{\mathbb{R}^3}+\|v-z\|^2_{\mathbb{R}^3}}
  $$
- Question. Is their any interesting **geometrical or topological properties** related to such mathematical object?
- Answer. As pointed out by Giuseppe Negro, the set $\Omega$ is a quadratic surface in $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is wrong in that $\Omega$ is not a vector space. If $\langle a_1, b_1\rangle_{\mathbb R^3} =\langle a_2, b_2\rangle_{\mathbb R^3} = 0$, then $\langle a_1+a_2, b_1+b_2\rangle_{\mathbb R^3}=\langle a_1, b_2\rangle_{\mathbb R^3}+ \langle a_2, b_1\rangle_{\mathbb R^3}$, and typically this is not zero. For a similar example, consider the set $\{ (x, y)\in \mathbb R^2\ :\ xy=0\}$. Clearly, this is not a vector space, however, it is the "kernel" of the bilinear form $(x, y)\mapsto xy$.

Comment: The set $\Omega$ is a quadratic surface in $\mathbb R^6$, and it is conceptually similar to the set $\{(x, y)\in \mathbb R^2\ :\ xy=0\}$ in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Giuseppe Negro, I corrected my answer. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

The set $\Omega_1=\{(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^3: \langle u, v \rangle=0, \|u\|=1\}$ is the tangent bundle of $S^2$, so one could use the metric on $TS^2$ to define a metric on $\Omega_1$.

The tangent bundle of $S^2$ is diffeomorphic to the set $z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2=1$ in $\mathbb{C}^3$, and so another metric can be defined by using its embedding in $\mathbb{R}^6$.